# How should make a broadcaster for Hokuyo utm 30lx?

Tags: hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to make a point cloud with laser Hokuyo utm30lx for this work I'm doing a transformation with TF, but I do not understand how to use the broadcaster with the sensor_msgs, I need an example subscription Hokuyo sensor data for the broadcaster .

I need to get the xyz coordinates of the sensor.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29163/how-should-make-a-broadcaster-for-hokuyo-utm-30lx?/) by [andresiguano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1921/andresiguano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I couldn't clearly understand your question!
but if your mean is , how to broadcast your laser scans tf , i should say you must measure your fixed laser coordinate manually , then set it to your laser scans tf broadcaster . and set frame_id : base_link  (your base tf).

for convert your laser shot to point cloud you can use of [laser_geometry](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_geometry) node  .

---

Originally posted by [farshid616](https://answers.ros.org/users/1501/farshid616/) with karma: 63 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0